# jquery ajax - resize of iframe of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am just beginner with ajax and jquery but I am trying to achieve this:

1. Page installation.html contains iframe with id="MyIframe" and src="step1.php"
2. Page step1.php contains button that calls step2.php using ajax (successfully)
3. Page step2.php need to has script, that will resize iframe of page installation.html (so the content of step2 will fit in)

So far , my script looks like this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'installation.html',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $(data).find('#MyIframe').height('1000px');
            },
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work. Can you suggest a solution here? Thank you.

Comment: you never insert `data` in page...just retrieve it from server and manipulate it. Need to use one of the multitude of jQuery insertion methods so you can see it

Comment: so how should it look like?

Comment: `$('#someContainer').html(data); $('#MyIframe').height('1000px')` Can change height first but I made this simple to put code in a comment blck

Comment: also confusing a bit which iframe is which... code provided assumes iframe is in new html from server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default jQuery uses `document` of current window as context - in your case it is `#MyIframe`. In this context there is no element with `#MyIframe` id. So you need to access your iframe from the top window's document:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window.top.document).find('#MyIframe').height('1000px');
});
</script>
```

Comment: What the- is window.top.document command and why I haven't heard of it. Well that's it, it works! Thank you man I owe you

Comment: `window.top` - the topmost browser window of the current window (in your case 'installation.html'). `document` is a DOM of that window.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, your code is not reflecting what you are trying to achieve at all.
The description you gave suggest you have the following structure.

installation.html

```
<iframe id="MyIframe" src="step1.php"></iframe>
```

step1.php

```
   button.click -> ajax GET step2.php -> resize #MyIframe
```

It's unclear to me why you load the step2.php page using ajax, can't you just change the `src` attribute of `#MyIframe` to `step2.php` and then resize the frame?

in step1.php

```
<button id="next">Next</button>

<script>
    $('#next').click(function () {
        $('#MyIframe', window.top.document).attr('src', 'step2.php').height(1000);
    });
</script>
```

If you need to POST values to step2.php, you could submit a form from `step1.php` instead of changing the src attribute of the iframe and use the same technique in step2.php to resize the top-level iframe.